# SSIS deployment very slow in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools

My team shares a SSIS Visual Studio 2015 Project (via GIT, I know it's not ideal), any everytime I deploy this project to the SQL Server SSIS Catalog, it takes **20 minutes or more**, from the third step ("changing protection level").

[image: Deployment Wizard]

I've asked my colleague to try the same thing, under the same conditions. We are on the same network, using the same Visual Studio version, deploying to the same server and using the same git commit. In her case, the deployment finishes very quickly **in a matter of seconds**.

Mostly i'm the one who performs changes in this project and a few months ago my deployments were also super fast. It feels like I'm "cluttering" my Visual Studio environment,  but I don't know how or why.

Can I get a few hints?

Comment: Is your visual studio version update to date with your peers (same minor version, patch, etc.)?  You may also want to try starting devenv.exe in safe mode using the /SafeMode switch, it could be an extension.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019

Comment: What protection level are you using? Encrypt with password, by any chance? Also, do you have to deploy the whole project? If I recall correctly, 2016 introduced the ability to deploy individual packages in the SSISDB deployment method.

Comment: @Larnu The protection level for every package is "DontSaveSensitive". I haven't tried to change the deployment method. From what I've read so far, it seems irreversible but I'll try.

Comment: @4e69636b If I start in SafeMode, the .dtproj is not recognizable, probably because it requires an extension, right?

Comment: I'm not saying you should change it, just that I've found that Encrypt with Password can take awhile to be undone.

Comment: @EduardoAlmeida that's right, the DTS capabilities are extensions so /SafeMode won't work - my mistake.  Have you tried repairing SSDT?  In the past I have had issues when updating Visual Studio to find out it broke some features of SSDT, but not all.  A repair on SSDT fixed those issues for me.  Worth a shot at least

Comment: Do not deploy from a remote share @EduardoAlmeida

Comment: @Arthur I'm deploying directly from my machine to the SQL Server SSIS Catalog.

Comment: @4e69636b So far I repaired Visual Studio and SSDT, to no avail. I'm going to start uninstalling (I don't know if disabling is enough) some extensions to try and find a culprit

Comment: I tried logging on my computer with another account, opened the Visual Studio (first time for this account) and the project deployment worked perfectly. So I assume it's something specific to my environment.  I tried resetting to default settings as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/07/16/reset-all-your-development-settings/) . My issue persists :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 and that did the trick.